# why my structure variable does not contain the changes applied by my handle functions

Tags: matlab, user-interface, structure, assign, handle

I created a structure that contains fields and a group of handles functions.
I initialized my structure when I press a button from my Matlab GUI, and then I proceed to call my handle functions, which either add new fields to my struct or update the default ones.
However, I have difficulty to see the changes, despite assigning the structure to my workspace, as I wish to call it in other functions to use the updated fields.

I used assignin(ws,var,val) and evalin(ws, expression)

```
function struct = initialisedStruct(arg)
    struct = struct ();    
    struct.a = arg;
    struct.b = 1;       

    struct.run= {...
         @aaaa,... %update some existed fields
         @bbbb, ...%add here a new field call c. -> struct.c now exists.
         @cccc,... %do something else
         };
end

function [applyToStructure] = applyMethod(applyToStructure, handles)
    for i = 1:length(handles)
        [applyToStructure] = handles{i}(applyToStructure);
    end
end

function clickOnThisButton(hObject, eventdata, handles)
    input = 12;
    struct = initialisedStruct(input);
    applyMethodHandles(struct, struct.run); %modify the struct
    assignin('base', 'struct', struct);
end

function clickOnAnotherButton(hObject, eventdata, handles)
    myvar = struct.c; % here is my problem as it does not exist
end
```

I was expected after applying applyMethodHandles which loops through each handle containing in the run field and using assignin, to see in the workspace my struct variable with its new fields.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not grabbing the output of the function. There are no references in matlab, you need to copy the new modified structure.

Instead of:

```
applyMethodHandles(struct, struct.run); %modify the struct
```

Do:

```
struct=applyMethodHandles(struct, struct.run); %modify the struct
```

Also `struct` is the worst name you can choose. Not only is bad programming because it says nothing about what it is, you are shadowing MATLABs `struct` name, so it can not use it. I strongly suggest changing the name.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your reply. Stupid mistakes I made. I used struct for the post :)